# Error daemonizing celery in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: celery, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to daemonize the celery worker for my django application. But I am facing the following error on checking celery status:

```
Starting Celery Service...
celery.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Failed to start Celery Service.
celery.service: Unit entered failed state.
celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The /etc/default/celeryd file code:

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"

CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="djangoapp"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/djangoapp/"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4"

CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/celery/log/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/celery/run/%n.pid"

CELERYD_USER="nobody"
CELERYD_GROUP="www-data"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

The /etc/systemd/system/celery.service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=nobody
Group=www-data

EnvironmentFile=-/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/celery

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'

ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have been trying to solve it for the last one hour but I am unable to solve it.

Someone please explain to me the reason behind the error and how to solve it.

Comment: What does `sudo service celery status` output say

Comment: I have listed the error at the top. The error is the output of sudo service celery status

Comment: `/home/djangoapp/` is an unusual directory are you sure it's correct and exists?

Comment: yes. I have my django backend code in that directory.